# Google Sheets says “spreadsheet too large” when it isn’t

Tags: google-sheets

I have an XLSX spreadsheet. It has 68251 rows and 94637 cells, and it's on-disk size is 1510842 bytes. When I try to upload it, Google claims that it exceeds the 400,000 cell limit.

The cell count here is the number of *non-empty* cells. The spreadsheet is created with Apache POI by a Java program. Some of the rows just have a sentence (of Korean) in the first column.

Some have a single word of Korean. Some have nothing at all, and are just there for visual whitespace.

Why does Google Sheets reject my spreadsheet?

Comment: How many columns are you using?

Comment: 2. Sometimes the first one has a long-ish string in it.

Comment: Are you using more than one sheet? If not, I don't understand how the number of cells isn't a multiple of the number of rows. Please add more information to your question.

Comment: And what’s the question?

Comment: Why does it reject my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Blank cells count towards the limit if they are within the range of non blank cells. The calculation is done by multiplying *the number of the last row with data* by the *number of the last column with data*

for example:

```
+----+---+---+---+
|    | A | B | C |
+----+---+---+---+
|  1 | x |   |   |
|  2 |   |   |   |
|  3 |   |   |   |
|  4 |   | x |   |
|  5 | x |   |   |
|  6 |   |   | x |
|  7 | x |   |   |
|  8 |   |   |   |
|  9 |   |   |   |
| 10 | x |   |   |
+----+---+---+---+
```

Although there are a lot of blank cells, and no more than once cell filled per row, the total cells calculation is 10 x 3 = 30

It is possible that non-visible characters are present in your spreadsheet (especially as your sheet was generated rather than manually created).

In a case such as the one below (if there is a space in the cell D4), there is no visual indicator of the final row.

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | A | B | C | D |
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | x |   |   |   |
| 2 | x |   |   |   |
| 3 |   | x |   |   |
| 4 |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

To find out for sure what your 'end' cell is, put the focus on A1, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> and the focus will move to the cell that is in the final row and the final column.

To remove any unwanted cells, select the first unwanted column, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right arrow</kbd>, then right-click and choose delete. Do a similar procedure to delete unwanted rows.

Comment: That would be 94637 * 1. There is never more than one cell filled on a row.

Comment: Do you only have data in column A?

Comment: Yes. that's correct.

Comment: It may be an artifact of Apache Poi. Ctrl-Shift-End should take you to B94637. Could you confirm this please?

Comment: No, it takes me way out to column CW. I guess that explains it.

Comment: I have updated the answer to use this approach and show you how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple sheets in your Excel spreadsheet, Google sheets will give this error and refuse to preview or open it.